# Google Sheets - Count Quotation Marks

Tags: google-sheets, escaping

Unfortunately the data I'm working with requires quotation marks, as it is entered into another system afterwards which requires it.

I'm trying to collect statistics, and need to count these entries. The only thing they have in common is they are wrapped in quotation marks.

I'm trying to use =COUNTIF($C3:$C, """) but it keeps changing it to =COUNTIF($C3:$C, "")"").

Is there a way to escape this so that i can count cells that contain a quotation mark (")?

Comment: Use `CODE(34)` to use the double quote character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Robin said, the most straightforward way to reference quotes is with the character code - for the double quote character it's `CHAR(34)`. One possible solution to this uses `QUERY()`, like so:

```
=QUERY($C3:$C, "Select count(C) where C contains '" & CHAR(34) & "' label count(C) ''", 0)
```

You can omit the `label count(C) ''` at the end if you're okay with it displaying a header cell, but adding it on contains the entire result to a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it seems to do what you want to do:

```
=COUNTIF(C3:C, "'*")
```

note the single quote mark.